# Price(#####) expected, got String(######) error. multiple tables and filling a drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms

I have viewed the other similar questions to this and attempted to fix my code with it but have been unable to do so.

When filling out the product form there are an array of prices to choose from, these prices are selected from the prices table where a user can pick a value and add an image.
The drop down menu appears in my code with all the prices a user has created. 
But after filling out the form and submitting the error:

```
Price(#45986840) expected, got String(#14456160)
```

appears

I have this in the products form

```
  <div id="field">
  <% price_array = Price.all.map {|price| [price.value, price.id]} %>
  <%= f.label :price %>
  <%= f.select :price, options_for_select(price_array) %>
  </div>
```

I'm pretty sure this is the problem, so I need to change this code to get it to store price in the table properly so as I can link the images to a given product with ease. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Change `<%= f.select :price, options_for_select(price_array) %>` to `<%= f.select :price_id, options_for_select(price_array) %>`

Comment: doing this gives `undefined method 'price_id'` do I need a foreign key in products that holds price_id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<%= f.select :price_id, Price.all.collect {|price| [price.value, price.id]} %>
```

Comment: to get this to work do I need to add a foreign key to products?
In my models I have a relationship set up like this, a price has_many products and a product has_one price.

Comment: Added the foreign Key to products and its working now, thanks allot.

Comment: Yes you will always need a foreign key. Just to point out, map and collect are exactly the same.